# bootstrap css classes hierarchy

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, workflow

I would like to learn how to build my css file using bootstrap elements. It's pretty tricky to try to select a unique element when all have pretty much the same classes so beside using id's how can I select a unique element from a structure like this one?

```
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">CREATED</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">MODIFIED</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">USER STATUS</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">STATUS</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">MODEL</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">26/02/2018</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">26/02/2018</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">quote requested</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <select class="form-control"></select>
              <button class="btn btn-default">SAVE</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <button class="btn btn-default">DOWNLOAD FILE</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <button class="btn btn-default">SELECT</button>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Let's assume I want the DOWNLOAD FILE button to have this property: width:50% . How can I select that particular button without giving him an id?

Comment: add another class for the button and specify the css for that class.

Comment: This is more a CSS question, than a Bootstrap question.

Comment: ..and what is wrong with an ID or even a separate class?

Comment: Or, in Bootstrap 4 just use the `w-50` class on the button.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Solution 1:

Use css selector instead of IDs.

Example:

```css
.row .col-lg-12 .row:nth-child(2) .col-md-2:nth-child(5) button.btn.btn-default {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

More: [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Here is the solution(1) of your question on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/carlocorradini/pen/vdoYWO).

## Solution 2:

Use a custom css class for the button(s).

Example:

```css
.btn-custom {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Here is the solution(2) of your question on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/carlocorradini/pen/aqebre).

Hope this helps.

Comment: PS: Remember CSS hierarchy.

Comment: That's definitely not an "easy and fast" selector.

Comment: I know, I answered his question following HTML structure given.

Comment: thank you @CarloCorradini ! The selectors where the ones I was looking for !